# Problem with check if bar is last of session with TradingView Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to detect last bar of custom session.
I'm using code from here: https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/last-session-bar/

Overall, the code works good, however for some cases it returns unexpected values.

Following code should draw red background on each 15:45 (EDT) bar, since it is last bar of US NYSE session (09:30-16:00 UTC-4).

```
//@version=5
indicator("last session bar",overlay = true)

// IsLastBarSession() returns 'true' when the current bar is the last
// of the specified session, adjusted for the given time zone (optional).
// Returns 'false' for other bars in the session, bars after the 
// session, and when the time frame is day or higher.
IsLastBarSession(sessionTime, sessionTimeZone=syminfo.timezone) =>
    var int lastBarHour   = na
    var int lastBarMinute = na
    var int lastBarSecond = na
    inSess = not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionTime, sessionTimeZone))

    if not inSess and inSess[1]
        lastBarHour   := hour[1]
        lastBarMinute := minute[1]
        lastBarSecond := second[1]
    
    hour == lastBarHour and minute == lastBarMinute and second == lastBarSecond

// Give the last bar of the 09:30 - 16:30 UTC-4 session a red background
bgcolor(IsLastBarSession("0930-1600", "UTC-4") ? 
     color.new(color.red, 80) : na)
```

In most cases, last bar is detected properly.

But sometime it detects last bar 90 minutes earlier than it should (despite the fact that 14:30 - 15:45 candles exists on chart). Why?

Ticker: COMEX:GC1!

Date: 5 Jul '22

Period: 15m (same thing with 30m, 1h, 2h)

[link to example on chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5tuI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was checking the closing time of previous day and using it in current day to find close
But since previous day candle closed at 14:15, it used that to plot the same
I have corrected it as below

```
//@version=5
indicator("last session bar",overlay = true,max_labels_count=500)

// IsLastBarSession() returns 'true' when the current bar is the last
// of the specified session, adjusted for the given time zone (optional).
// Returns 'false' for other bars in the session, bars after the 
// session, and when the time frame is day or higher.
IsLastBarSession(sessionTime, sessionTimeZone=syminfo.timezone) =>
    var int lastBarHour   = na
    var int lastBarMinute = na
    var int lastBarSecond = na
    inSess = not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionTime, sessionTimeZone))

    not inSess and inSess[1]
    
// Give the last bar of the 09:30 - 16:30 UTC-4 session a red background
bgcolor(IsLastBarSession("0930-1600", "UTC-4") ? 
     color.new(color.red, 80) : na,-1)
```